# Project from view so that the UVs match the background image

Tags: texturing, uv

Is there a way to use the "project from view" unwrapping method so that the resulting UVs automatically line up with the image, if the same image is used both for the background image and the texture?

At least for me it's a very common workflow to model something on top of a background image and then unwrap with the "project from view method". But I always end up having to scale and move the UV's to match the image, which feels unnecessary, since I already modeled everything to match the BG image perfectly.

Can Blender do this? If not, would it be difficult to write a a script or addon to do this?

Comment: There is absolutely no relation between background images and UV space coordinates as far as I know

Comment: Last few days back i saw in youtube on how to model a wine bottle..by Miguel Barosso..and the way he teached is what you wanted..i believe..please go to https://youtu.be/ujtbWn-iGIA

Answer (score 3):

Use **Project from View Bounds** instead of *Project from View*.